# Configure Jacoco with gradle and kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, jacoco, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to configure Jacoco to exclude some classes from analysis but can't find any working example :(

I found some samples with `afterEvaluate` but no success

Comment: Please add an example on what you tried or your current `build.gradle` file and add details what exactly does not work as you expect.

Comment: All that i've tried, don't even compile. So i've no relevant example to provide

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`src/main/java/org/example/A.java`:

```java
package org.example;

class A {
}
```

`src/main/java/org/example/B.java`:

```java
package org.example;

class B {
}
```

`src/test/java/org/example/ExampleTest.java`:

```java
package org.example;

public class ExampleTest {
  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
    new A();
    new B();
  }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
  java
  jacoco
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
}
```

using Gradle 5.4.1 execution of `gradle test jacocoTestReport` produces following report

[image: report]

after addition to `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
  classDirectories.setFrom(
    sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
      exclude("org/example/B.class")
    }
  )
}
```

execution of the same command produces following report

[image: report after exclusion]

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to @Godin's awesome answer:

The way @Godin explained it, you would have to run  `gradle test jacocoTestReport` which isn't bad but If you want jacoco to run when you run just with `gradle test` add this to your build.gralde.kts:

```kotlin
tasks.test {
    finalizedBy("jacocoTestReport")
    doLast {
        println("View code coverage at:")
        println("file://$buildDir/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to exclude this way:

```kotlin
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        files(classDirectories.files.map {
            fileTree(it) {
                exclude(
                    "com/example/integration/**",
                    "com/example/application/*Ext*"
                )
            }
        })
    )
}
```

Taken [from here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1176)